# Webpack: Dynamically create <img> from images in a directory

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, dynamic

My simplified filesystem:

```
|webpack.config.js
|package.json
|dist
   |-index.html
|src
   |-index.js
   |card
      |-card.js
   |images
      |-imageImporter.js
      |-coffee.jpg
      |-chocolate.jpg
      |-...
```

I want to write something along the lines of:

#### imageImporter.js

```js
const images = [];
const imageContext = require.context('./', false, /\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/);

imageContext.keys().forEach((imagePath) => {
  images.push(imagePath);
});

export default images;
```

Puts all the image paths in an array `images`

#### index.js

```js
import images from './images/imageImporter.js';
import {dom_createCard} from './card/card.js';
let dom_contentDiv = document.querySelector('div#content');

const dom_createCardsHolder = () => {

    let dom_cardsHolder = document.createElement('div');

    for (let i=0; i< images.length; i++) {
        let imagePath = "../images/"+images[i].substring(2);
        let dom_card = dom_createCard(imagePath); // THE CALL IS HERE
        dom_cardsHolder.appendChild(dom_card);
    }

    return dom_cardsHolder;
}

dom_contentDiv.appendChild(dom_createCardsHolder());
```

Puts all image cards in the `dom_cardsHolder`

#### card.js

```js
require.context('../images', false, /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/);

const dom_createCard = (imagePath) => {
    let dom_card = document.createElement('img');
    console.log("image path given to me is:"+ imagePath);
    // Prints: image path given to me is:../images/coffee.jpg

    dom_card.src = imagePath; // WHAT TO DO HERE INSTEAD?

    dom_card.width = 300; 
    return dom_card;
}


export {dom_createCard};
```

Creates image card

#### package.json

```json
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ],
    },
```

### Bug

Things don't work. After printing all the image paths it gives me:
`GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/images/<Image Name>.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

## Note

If in `card.js` i do instead

```js
import coffeeImage from '../images/coffee.jpg'
// ...
const dom_createCard = (imagePath) => {
    // ...
    dom_card.src = coffeeImage;
    // ...
}
// ...
```

It works (but it just prints the `coffee.jpg` and not the other images)

Comment: Doesn't webpack build a client module? This means the module doesn't have directory access to the server. (That last example likely works because the import is getting translated into a useable url-like thing.) You'd either need to build a static list of images or a way for the module to request a list of images from the server.

Comment: (I have basic webpack knowledge :_) Do you mean I have to do`import coffeeImage from '../images/coffee.jpg'` + `import chocolateImage from '../images/chocolate.jpg'` and so on, and then to statically do `dom_cardCoffee.src = coffeeImage;` + `dom_cardChocolate.src = chocolateImage;`  and so on? No dynamic version?

Comment: I suspect `dom_card.src = '../images/coffee.jpg';` also works. (not 100% sure on that, there may be some magic that converts a pathname to the correct relative url.) As for dynamically, you'd set up a url on the server that emits a list of the image names. Then the client module would be set up to retrieve that url and use it to create the cards.

Comment: @Ouroborus , unfortunately it still prints `GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/images/coffee.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Ouroborus, but doing `console.log(coffeeImage); // the address it gives me i use next`
    `dom_card.src = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/<Random_Number_It_Gave_Me>.jpg';` does work, but i don't know if there's a way of getting this random number from the path name. I imagine this is where what you said about a server is needed...